# form.is_valid() is not running on first visit?

Tags: django

When the page is first loaded, the initial form values are loaded but `if form.is_valid()` did not run (I know this for certain from some testing).  Why?

**views**

```
def view(request):

    form = FilterForm(request.GET or None)
    question_list = []
    if form.is_valid():
        if form.cleaned_data['all_questions'] == True:
            question_list = Question.objects.all().order_by('date_created')
        else:
            # create appropriate queryset
```

**forms**

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):

    all_questions = forms.BooleanField(initial=True, required=False)
    question_type_a = forms.BooleanField(initial=False, required=False)
    question_type_b = forms.BooleanField(initial=False, required=False)
```

---

SOLUTION:

**Just have to check `is_bound` in views**

```
def view(request):

    form = FilterForm(request.GET or None)
    question_list = []
    if not form.is_bound:
         question_list = Question.objects.all().order_by('date_created')
    if form.is_valid():
        if form.cleaned_data['all_questions'] == True:
            question_list = Question.objects.all().order_by('date_created')
        else:
            # create appropriate queryset
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to help you. What are you passing as GET params on the initial page load?

Comment: why are you using filter_1 three times in the `FilterForm` class?

Comment: @akimul Sorry I meant it to be `filter_1`, `filter_2` ... to demonstrate that this is a filter form

Comment: @solarissmoke I edited the question.  The initial information should be the form defaults, meaning all_questions is true and all questions should be displayed.  However when the page is first loaded the question_list is empty, meaning the `form.is_valid()` is skipped on initial visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. When you first load the page without any GET parameters, the form hasn't been submitted, so there is no data for any of the fields. `None` will be passed to the form constructor, becaus `request.GET` is empty. This means you have initialised an *unbound* form.

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#bound-and-unbound-form-instances):

> The distinction between bound and unbound forms is important:
>
> - An unbound form has no data associated with it. When rendered to the user, it will be empty or will contain default values.
> - A bound form has submitted data, and hence can be used to tell if that data is valid. If an invalid bound form is rendered, it can include inline error messages telling the user what data to correct.

Calling `is_valid()` on an unbound form will always return `False`.

You probably need to modify your logic to check `is_bound()` on the form, and use that to decide what to render if the form has no data.

Comment: Thank you.  I did not know this.  2 lines and code and the problem is solved.